# extract multiple URLs using the datetime function

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, url, beautifulsoup, python-requests

In this program i am not using request or beautiful soup function. I'm instead only using the datetime to extract the URLs. Now in the current program, I have written to extract the values for a long period. I want to make it in such a way that, if I automate this program and it runs today, it will extract yesterday's data. Similarly if it runs tomorrow, it will extract todays data and so on.

here is the code,

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, datetime,timedelta
import warnings
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import wget
import glob
import os
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
from urllib.error import HTTPError

def date_range(start_date,end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date-start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

def get_urls(base_url):
    part_two = "/dailyCoal1-"
    end_part = ".xlsx"
    start_date = date(2020,11,1)
    end_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    start_urls = list()
    for single_date in date_range(start_date, end_date):
        start_urls.append(single_date.strftime(base_url+'%d-%m-%Y'+part_two+'%Y-%m-%d'+end_part))
    return start_urls
    
def excel_download(link,out):
    #downloads a given link provided to a output directory in out 
    wget.download(link,out)
    
if __name__ =="__main__":
    base_url = "https://npp.gov.in/public-reports/cea/daily/fuel/"
    mypath = "/Users/vp/Desktop/temp"
    temp_folder = '/Users/vp/Desktop/temp'
    out_folder = "/Users/vp/Desktop/NPP"
    log_file = os.path.join(out_folder,'debug_log_npp.log')
    out_file = os.path.join(out_folder,'Energy_inputs_npp.csv')
    file_links = get_urls(base_url)
    for link in file_links:
        try:
            excel_download(link,temp_folder)
        except HTTPError:
            content = "HTTP issue while capturing data for this link - " + link
            log_writer(log_file,content)
            continue
        file = glob.glob(os.path.join(temp_folder,'*.xlsx'),recursive=True)[0]
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
```

To capture yesterday's data, i created this in the main function where i check for yesterday = and then cancel if it isnt yesterday. But then its throwing error as it constantly picks the start date as its day one.

```
if(date_time_obj != Yesterday):
    os.remove(file)
    content = "Date mis-matched - " + str(date_time_obj) + " " + str(Yesterday)
```

In this program, date_time_obj - is the date it is currently trying to extract data for.

Everyday if this program runs at 8pm, it needs to only capture one day before data on a daily basis.

if this cannot be done in datetime, but only on request or bs4, then how do i approach this problem?

Comment: If you print out the return value from the function get_urls, does it conform to the url values you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you wanted a valid link as your code doesn't seem to produce those for me but you only need to tweak to work off start_date only and return a single item to return yesterday's link matching with your current output for same date.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, datetime,timedelta
import warnings
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
from urllib.error import HTTPError

def get_url(base_url):
    part_two = "/dailyCoal1-"
    end_part = ".xlsx"
    start_date = datetime.datetime.now().date() + timedelta(-1)
    start_url = start_date.strftime(base_url+'%d-%m-%Y'+part_two+'%Y-%m-%d'+end_part)
    return start_url
    
def excel_download(link,out):
    #downloads a given link provided to a output directory in out 
    wget.download(link,out)
    
if __name__ =="__main__":
    base_url = "https://npp.gov.in/public-reports/cea/daily/fuel/"
    mypath = "/Users/vp/Desktop/temp"
    temp_folder = '/Users/vp/Desktop/temp'
    out_folder = "/Users/vp/Desktop/NPP"
    log_file = os.path.join(out_folder,'debug_log_npp.log')
    out_file = os.path.join(out_folder,'Energy_inputs_npp.csv')
    file_link = get_url(base_url)
    
print(file_link)
```